# Magento2 backend routes

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento2-dev-beta

I'm currently writing a Magento 2 extension to add Product attachments. In my extension I add an extra tab on the admin product page called 'Downloads'. In this tab several upload inputs are shown where the user can add a product attachment. My upload function works, but now I want to add the possibility to remove the attachment.

I know how to write the Model functions, but how can I create a route that points to a Adminhtml controller where my delete function is.

I already added an adminhtml/routes.xml which contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="sample_productdownloads" frontName="sample_productdownloads">
            <module name="Sample_ProductDownloads" before="Magento_Backend" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

This is my controller, located in: Controller\Adminhtml\Index folder.

```
<?php
namespace Sample\ProductDownloads\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Sample\ProductDownloads\Model\Download;

class Index extends Action
{

    /**
     * @var Download
     */
    private $download;

    /**
     * @param Action\Context $context
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Sample\ProductDownloads\Model\Download $download
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        die('test');
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access the page from: http://magento.dev/admin/sample_productdownloads/index/index

It's very hard to debug why this is not working because I keep getting redirected to Magento backend home.

Thanks.

Comment: The route looks right. Please post the path to the controller, the code in the controller and how you are calling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVC in Magento 2 is a bit different from the classical MVC.
A controller does not contain multiple actions.
A controller is an action in Magento 2. And in order for this controller to be accessed it needs to have an `execute` method.
Change

```
public function index()
{
    die('test');
}
```

to

```
public function execute()
{
    die('test');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I could not figure this out due to a combination of the wrong function / cache. Now I can reach my extension via  sample_productdownloads/index/index. The concept is clear, I made a folder with Download and added the class Delete so I can reach it like: sample_productdownloads/download/delete. 

But how does dependency injection works on this Action? I get a message: Recoverable Error: Argument 2 passed to <class>::__construct() must implement interface Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface, null given.

Comment: post in the question the `Delete.php` file so I can have a better view.

Comment: I cleared the cache a few times, but still the Dependency Injection did not work. I disabled / enabled the extension, after that it did work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who has an equal problem, my problem was the execute function as Marius explained. Further I included the wrong Action, the class should be:

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
```

Instead of

```
Magento\Backend\App\Action;
```